# Transfer case is leaking, is it easy to fix myself?

Tags: jeep, transfer-case

My 1993 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo's transfer case is leaking. I took it into the shop, and was quoted $600 to fix it. After doing some research online, it seems that there are several quick things to check for such as tight plugs, and getting more complicated from there.

The leak is where the transmission meets the case.

Is this type of leak easy to fix, and can it be done without any specialized tools?

Comment: Do you know where in the case the leak is coming from?  A seal? A crack even?

Comment: @Chenmunka, good question, there is no crack, it is where the transmission meets the case (seal). I've also updated the question.

Comment: To fix the leak the transfer case would have to be separated from the transmission. This requires the removal of the transfer case. The question you have to ask yourself is "Do I want to remove the transfer case?"

Comment: At a minimum (and what @vini_i is alluding to) you'll need a transmission jack to do this job safely. That's not something most people have lying around, nor would I want to purchase for a one time job.

Comment: $600 seems like a lot for a seal replacement on a transfer case. book time (R&I) is 1.8 hrs then it depends on what's leaking, seals range from 0.2 to 1.2 hrs. I'd shop around a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the laredo particularly, but on any car this isn't a particularly simple job. It requires special tools, and you may need to remove other parts to get to the transfer case and transmission. Some of this may be big or heavy, so you might need an extra pair of hands.

At the least you will need jacks to get under the car, and some sort of jack to support the transmission and/or lower the transfer case. You may need special tools to remove the seals and insert the new ones.

It's the sort of job a reasonably competent and well-equipped amateur mechanic can tackle, you'll have to gauge for yourself if that's you.